# UITextView becomesFirstResponder animation jitters when UIViewController being pushed

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation, uitextfield

I am working on the latest version of iOS 8 GM.

Using a `UINavigationController`, I'm trying to push a `UIViewController` containing a simple `UITextField` and make the keyboard pop in the same animation than the push.

On iOS 7, everything worked great, but on iOS 8, there is a suspect jitter that make the animation ugly.
In my code, nothing crazy, I just call

```
[self.titleTextField performSelector:@selector(becomeFirstResponder) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
```

in my `viewWillAppear:animated:` implementation.

After spending some time, I think this is on Apple side, but I wonder if some of you have found some workarounds ?

Thanks !

Comment: Did you try putting [self.titleTextField becomeFirstResponder]; in viewDidAppear ?

Comment: Yeah it works, but does not result in the animation I want to happen. My keyboard has to slide as if it was pushed in the same time than my new UIViewController.

Comment: What if you give it a longer delay ?

Comment: Same thing, it works as long as I provide a longer delay than the push animation duration. However, the animation is still wrong and will be similar to the viewDidAppear solution.